# canvas.toDataURL() returns [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, discord.js, node-canvas

Can someone please tell me why `canvas.toDataURL()` shows `[object Promise]`? I want to load a `node-canvas` image on my website with an image tag in HTML. Here is my code:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('updateImage', async function (id, user) {
    const welcome = new Keyv(`sqlite://data/welcome/${id}.sqlite`);
    const bgimg = await welcome.get('canvas-join-bgimg') ? await welcome.get('canvas-join-bgimg') : `https://i.imgur.com/XMPcnz1.jpeg`;

    const Canvas = require('canvas');

    const background = await Canvas.loadImage(bgimg);
    const avatardash = await Canvas.loadImage(user.displayAvatarURL({
        dynamic: true,
        size: 1024
    }));

    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    return new Handlebars.SafeString(
        '<img src='
        ' + canvas.toDataURL() + '
        ' />'
    );
});
```

Sorry, but I'm still learning, and I do not see anything of this on the web.

**EDIT:** Here you can see the result on my website:


[image: Result]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have not yet awaited the promise, therefore the promise is unresolved.

Awaiting the promise is simple, simply add the `await` keyword:

```js
return new Handlebars.SafeString(
  `<img src="${await canvas.toDataURL()}">`
);
```

The above code is awaiting the promise and using template literals to avoid string concatenation.